# Select a file from media modal box on joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, modal-dialog, joomla2.5

I use on my Joomla component this snippet to call the image box and populate with his value my field:

```
<a class="modal" title="Select your image" href="index.php?option=com_media&amp;view=images&amp;tmpl=component&amp;asset=59&amp;author=42&amp;fieldid=id_field&amp;folder=" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 500}}">Select your image</a>
```

It works fine.

But If I need of an other type of file?
I tried so:

```
<a class="modal" title="Select your file" href="index.php?option=com_media&amp;view=media&amp;tmpl=component&amp;asset=59&amp;author=42&amp;fieldid=id_field&amp;folder=" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 500}}">Select your file</a>
```

> with view=**media** instead of  view=**images**

I see the modal box with media files.. but I can't select them to populate my field..

why?
Thanks!

Comment: Did You find a solution for that? I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, I hope I don't mess up again. If it is the com_media you can see it here: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2253464

Comment: This post talk about how use com_media to include images.  I can already do it. My problem is how use com_media to include other type of files (pdf, doc etc). This solution displays only images.